# Which GUI toolkit would it make sense to wrap in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am currently using a Java framework called Vaadin with Clojure and I wish there was already a native Clojure wrapping for this. I was wondering which GUI frameworks it would make sense to wrap with Clojure for an awesome web app developmkent experience?

Comment: I think the answer will depends a lot on your target platform - are you looking for web apps only, or would a desktop GUI app be just as good? what about mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a canonical and complete swing wrapper around yet. There are bit's and pieces, but no real wrappers. Swing being the canonical GUI toolkit for the JVM, it would make sense to wrap it.

Another viable option is Jambi, which would be great as well. I think it makes sense for there to be wrappers for both of them.